# What is the principle due to which the QQ plots work and give a straight line if the sample data belongs to that distribution?

Tags: statistics

I understand that if I have a sample of data which follow Normal Distribution then if I plot the sample data's quantiles against the normal theoretical quantiles then I will observe that the points are closely following a straight line. But why are these points following the straight line? What is the principle based on which this method is working?

Comment: if they are the same distribution then they have the same quantiles

Answer (score 1):

Take a sample `x` of size $n = 100$ from a normal population as an example. Sampling and computations in R:

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rnorm(100, 50, 7)
summary(x)
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 29.70   46.71   51.20   50.97   56.06   70.21
```

An empirical CDF (ECDF) of the sample is made by sorting the sample from smallest to largest. Starting at height $0$ on the left, we make a graph that jumps up by $1/n$ at each observation and reaching height $1$ at the right. For a reasonably large sample, the ECDF is
similar to the CDF of the population. In the plot below the ECDF is
the black 'stairstep' and the CDF is the orange curve.

```
plot(ecdf(x))
curve(pnorm(x, 50, 7), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
```

[image]

The idea of a normal probability plot (Q-Q plot) is to use the quantile function (inverse CDF) to straighten the orange curve so it becomes a straight line
with slope $\sigma = 7$ and y-intercept $\mu = 50.$

```
plot(qqnorm(x))
abline(a = 50, b=7, lwd=2, col="orange")
```

[image]

Sometimes in software, the reference line of the Q-Q plot
runs through the theoretical quartiles and the quartiles of the data.
Often, as in my example, there is little difference in the orientation of the two lines.

The main idea of a Q-Q plot is for the data
to lie approximately along *a line* (with some tolerance for a *few* points
near the maximum and minimum that may stray from the linear pattern).

```
plot(qqnorm(x));  qqline(x, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

In some countries (including those in North America) it has become
customary to plot data quantiles on the *horizontal* axis.
Then using the quartiles to make the line is a slight
simplification.

```
plot(qqnorm(x, datax=T))
qqline(x, datax=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

In statistical practice, normal Q-Q plots are
often used to check whether a sample comes from
a normal distribution. If not, the departure of
the plotted points can be easy to see. (Especially
for small samples, many statisticians prefer to look
at such plots instead of relying on formal goodness-of-fit
tests, which may have poor power to detect non-normality.)

Below are *normal* Q-Q plots of a sample from an exponential
distribution and a sample from a uniform distribution.

[image]

R code for above plot:

```
set.seed(217)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 w = rexp(50)  # sample of size 50
 qqnorm(w, main="Norm Q-Q Plot; Exponential Data")
  qqline(w, col="blue", lwd=2)
 u = runif(50) # sample of size 50
 qqnorm(u, main="Norm Q-Q Plot: Uniform Data")
  qqline(u, col="blue", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

*Note:* The same idea of turning ECDFs into linear
plots is used to make Q-Q plots based on non-normal *distributions.*